# How to extract a value from an Array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects `Foo` :

```
let a, b, c = new Foo()
let l: Array<Foo> = [a, b, c]

evaluateFoo(f: Foo): boolean {
 ...
}
```

I am currently using a `map` to basically convert my list of `Foo` to an array of `boolean` (with the `evaluteFoo` function). Ultimately, what I want to get is either `true` or `false` --> either one of the `evaluateFoo` functions return `true`, or not, and I return `false`.

Currently, to do so I am first doing : l.map(f => evaluateFoo(f)) and then I go true the new array and do the check to see if one of the value is true.

As you understood this is tedious for something quite easy. Any other rxjs operator that could help me having something simpler ?

Comment: how is this connected to rxjs? I don't see any rxjs operator; I don't even see a need in rxjs when it is about a simple array and some objects. And finally I don't understand why `evaluateFoo` is not a method of `Foo` because it seems like it should belong to `Foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that what you are looking for?

```
[1, 2, 3].some(e => e > 3)
> false
[1, 2, 3, 4].some(e => e > 3)
> true
```

where 1, 2, 3 are your `Foo`s and `e => e > 3` is your evaluation function